# Is it able to import from a module named uid_2014-10-13.py?

Tags: python

I used python's datetime module to generate date oriented uid file.

But I find that I can't import from `uid_2014-10-13.py'

seems that python think these '-' in `2014-10-13` are `minus` operator.

Am I able to import from that module in another way or should I rename it?

Comment: Rename it - modules should have valid identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still import it, using [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

```
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module('uid_2014-10-13')
```

However, you should really produce module names that are also valid Python identifiers; e.g. no dashes. If you used the `datetime` module, consider using `datetime.date.strftime()` to format your date with underscores, for example.

Demo:

```
>>> open('uid_2014-10-13.py', 'w').write('print "Hello world!"\n')
>>> import importlib
>>> module = importlib.import_module('uid_2014-10-13')
Hello world!
>>> module
<module 'uid_2014-10-13' from 'uid_2014-10-13.py'>
```